# How do you get the version of installed addin in a provider hosted solution?

Tags: csom, version

I am trying to get the version of an installed provider hosted addin. I need this to control the update process. However, I have found no way of doing this except with SharePoint Online: [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt637897.aspx)

I basically don't have the Tenants table, so is there some other way of getting the version number of an installed provider hosted addin? I need to do this in C#.

Note: The app will be installed on a local farm, that's why I have no access to the tenants table.

I already have tried the following code. However, I always get a `NullReferenceException` when trying to read `VersionString` and `ServerObjectIsNull` is always true

```
private static Version GetTenantVersion()
{
    Version returnVersion = new Version("0.0.0.0");
    Web web = context.Web;
    context.Load(web);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    var instances = AppCatalog.GetAppInstances(context, web);
    context.Load(instances);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    var instance = instances.Where(a => a.Title.Contains(AppNameString)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (instance != null)
    {
        context.Load(instance);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        App previousAppVersion = instance.GetPreviousAppVersion();
        context.Load(previousAppVersion, p => p.VersionString);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        if (previousAppVersion.ServerObjectIsNull.HasValue && !previousAppVersion.ServerObjectIsNull.Value)
            returnVersion = new Version(previousAppVersion.VersionString);
    }

    return returnVersion;
}
```

Comment: Did you upgrade your app before accessing `GetPreviousAppVersion()`?

Comment: I dind't upgrade as-in. I just redeployed my existing solution from within Visual Studio.

Comment: `GetPreviousAppVersion` works only  for upgraded apps, like spec implies: `Retrieves the version of the app that is being upgraded from during an upgrade.` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spappinstance.getpreviousappversion.aspx)

Comment: So this object will only be non-null when the app is actually upgraded? Even when, let's say, I go back to the setup page using my browser and debug again. Then this property is still null, even though the app installed succesfully?

Comment: Yes, from my POV it will be null. One option is to put `SPAddInVersion` in your appmanifest, like [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/SharePoint_Provider-hosted_Add-ins_Tutorials/blob/master/7_BeforeProgrammaticButton/ChainStore/AppManifest.xml) not sure if that helpful for you..

Comment: I already have it in my app manifest. But I need to read the installed version during an upgrade. I could add a key to my web.config file that basically will do the same. What do you think?

Comment: In that case may be the easiest way is to create a list on an app web and track version information inside that list?

Comment: ok I will keep that in mind. thanks for the hints!